# Find the gradient of $cf(x^Tg(z))$ with respect to x

Tags: derivatives, optimization, vector-analysis

As I understand it should be something like this:

$$\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}=(cf'g(z))^T$$

but I saw that

$$(g(z)cf')^T$$

Which one is correct? maybe none..

Comment: what is the domain and codomain of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: $f$ & $g$ are functions, I don't know what do you mean by domain and codomain

Comment: A function takes on values in one space and maps them to another space. I.e. $f:X\mapsto Y$ for sets $X,Y$. What are $X$ and $Y$ for $f$ and $g$? Do you mean $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$? Is that correct?

Comment: $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R^{n\times n}}, f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R^n}$